# Hibernate validator - conditionally apply validator

Tags: validation, hibernate-validator

I want to apply certain @NotBlank annotations only if another field is false. On my current project we have to use hibernate validator, so no commons validation + valang available to solve this.

Since I'm not too fond of creating multiple custom annotations just to solve what should be an easy thing (bit bummed that this isn't part of the JSR-303 spec) I was wondering if anyone knew an acceptable way to accomplish this. I found a jar which accomplished that, but that was  for hibernate 3. And due to the changes...

Comment: Are you get the best way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

For this case, the suggested approach is to use class-level constraints instead Field or Property Level.

Please refer [Hibernate Validator Docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#d0e326)

I now it is annoying. I had a scenario like this and tried something like *@NotEmpty(depends="anotherField")* and it was a totally failure.

Maybe some other members know another way to do this, but for now, I'm doing what Hibernate Validator says to do.

Comment: To be honest, in my opinion the lack of support for such a scenario is one of my pet peeves with the JSR-303 spec. And class level constraints are nice and all, but they do not give you the same flexibility with placing and customizing your error messages.

Comment: Agreed, but I thing is just a matter of separation of concerns. Field validations are specifically to one Field/Property (empty, null, greater than X, lower than Y). Those are immutable validations that are not supposed to depend to any other part of the system. You will never get confused with that. Otherwise, someone could create a validation madness in just one field.

Comment: @Beccari If my situation is that if field1 = true then validate the other one. And let's say my other field is a class object, and for now I am just using @Valid on it. If I were to make this if-else sort of thing, I will have to write the validation mechanism for my other field all by myself right? I can not use `@Valid` any longer

Comment: @Kraken I believe so. if you remove the <code>@Valid</code> from the object field , the validation will never 'enter' on its fields - to do a <code>@NotNull</code> validation for instance. If you want this object field to be validated, your class-level validation will have to deal with it, manually calling the validator.validate() based on field1 = true.